# Consecutive losses in a row

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Been trying to modify this existing script. It stops trading after we incur the set amount of consecutive losses in a row.

Problem is once the script stops it never starts back up again.

I've tried numerous iterations but had no luck.

Once stop trading after 'X' amount of consecutive losses is there a way to wait until we have 'X' amount of buy/sell signals before re-entering the market???

(FYI. This script I've posted stops after 'X' amount of losses)

````
strategy(title="Stop after losing streak", overlay=false, precision=0,
     default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, default_qty_value=5)


// Set the max losing streak length with an input
maxLosingStreak = input.int(15, title="Max Losing Streak Length", minval=1)

// Calculate moving averages
fastMA = ta.ema(close, 5)
slowMA = ta.ema(close, 25)

// Determine trading conditions
enterLong  = ta.crossover(fastMA, slowMA)
enterShort = ta.crossunder(fastMA, slowMA)


// Check if there's a new losing trade that increased the streak
newLoss = strategy.losstrades > strategy.losstrades[1] and
     strategy.wintrades == strategy.wintrades[1] and
     strategy.eventrades == strategy.eventrades[1]


// Determine current losing streak length
streakLen = 0


streakLen := if newLoss
    nz(streakLen[1]) + 1
else
    if strategy.wintrades > strategy.wintrades[1] or
         strategy.eventrades > strategy.eventrades[1]
        0
    else
        nz(streakLen[1])

// Show current losing streak and its limit on chart
plot(streakLen, style=plot.style_columns,
     color=streakLen < maxLosingStreak ? color.maroon : color.red)

bgcolor(newLoss ? color.new(color.red, 80) : na)

hline(maxLosingStreak, color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_solid,
     linewidth=2)
hline(0, linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.gray)


// See if losing streak is under max allowed
okToTrade = streakLen < maxLosingStreak


// Submit orders, with consideration for current losing streak
if okToTrade and enterLong
    strategy.entry("EL", strategy.long)

if okToTrade and enterShort
    strategy.entry("ES", strategy.short)


else if not okToTrade
    strategy.close("EL")
    strategy.close("ES")


plotshape(enterLong, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green)
plotshape(enterShort, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red)```
````